# Reset excel workbook password programmatically using c#

Tags: c#, excel, passwords, reset

Is it possible to reset/rewrite password in excel workbook using c#?

I tried to do a couple things, but it did't solve my question:

1) `workbook.Password = "";` doesn't help

2) `workbook.Protect ("",true,true);`

```
workbook.Unprotect(""); doestn't help
```

3) I also tried to resave `workbook.SaveAs(workbook.FullName,XlNormal,"","",false,null,Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,null,false,null,null,false);`

If you have any idea, please help.

Comment: I think you have to provide the correct password, than it should work.

Comment: my question is how to reset password. Even if i know the correct password i want to reset it. And work with unprotected workbook

Comment: If it could be possible such easy - there would not be so many payable solutions for Excel password reset))))

Comment: Maybe you can advice wich way to dig

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the way to go is

```
workbook.Unprotect(pwd);
```

But to have it work you need to pass it the correct password, i.e. `string.Empty` is not enough.

Be careful that password protection can be put not only on workbooks, but even on the single worksheets, so it could be better to loop on the sheets and call `Unprotect` on them, too.

If you don't know the password, [here](http://www.mcgimpsey.com/excel/removepwords.html) you can find an excel macro that can unprotect your file. It shouldn't be too difficult to translate it into C if you really need to.